# Construct basis functions that contains its derivative and multiplication with $x$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I am not a mathematician, please forgive my inaccurate mathematical language for asking the following question and feel free to edit it (and the tags) to be more precise.

Assume that $\{\phi_{k}(x)\}_{k=1}^{n}$ ($n \neq\infty$), $x\in[a,b]$, forms a basis for a vector space of functions in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\phi_{k}(x)$). I would like to find/construct these $\phi_{k}(x)$ in way that satisfy the following conditions:

1. There exists a natural number $m$ $\in$ $\{1,..,n\}$ such that $\frac{d}{dx} \phi_{k}(x)=c_m \phi_{m}(x)$, for some constant $c_m$.
2. There exists a natural number $j$ $\in$ $\{1,..,n\}$ such that $x \phi_{k}(x)=c_j \phi_{j}(x)$, for some constant $c_j$.

Consider, for instance, $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^{n-1}\}$ basis functions, which is very close to meet these condtions. The first one is met but the second condition is not met because $xx^{n-1}=x^{n}$ is not a basis function.

Does such a space exist?

And if $n=\infty$, is the space of polynomials the only space that meets these conditions?

Comment: The vector space of functions in $\mathbb{R}$ is not finite dimensional.  Therefore, you cannot find a finite basis.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Please see the second part of the question as well (added after your comment)

Comment: When "$n = \infty$", how should we interpret your conditions exactly?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. Do you mean, my question does not make sense?

Comment: Exactly. Because, you use $n$ as a number in your conditions. You need to change your conditions as well, I think.

Comment: I am not sure whether I agree on this. If you consider the space of all polynomilas,these conditions are met, I believe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141348/discussion-between-alns-and-mirar).

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are looking for.

The wording of 1 and 2 implies that $m$ and $j$ are the same for any $k$. That would eliminate anything non-trivial.

If we accept that that is not the case, then we have a bit of a problem.

1 is satisfied fairly easily. The polynomial functions you gave are one choice; so is any finite Fourier basis ($\{ 1, \sin x, \cos x, \sin 2x, \cos 2x...\}$), and you can do the same thing with hyerbolic functions, exponential functions and a whole host of other things.

2 can not be true in any finite set.

Trivially, if 2 was true, then any $x^{n} \phi_{k}(x)$ would be in your basis set, for any $n$,any $k$.

It can't have a Taylor or a Maclaurin expansion, because that would imply that, for any $n$, your basis set contains an analytical function whose Taylor expansion has first $n$ terms equal to zero. So either your set is infinite, or all it contains is zero.

Can it have some singularity of exponential or higher order at zero?

But again, $x\phi_{k}$ would have a lower order singularity than $\phi_{k}$; $x^{2}\phi_{k}$ lower than $x\phi_{k}$ and so on. So for any $k, n$, your set would have to contain something with singularity of the order lower than $x^{n}\phi_{k}$.

So, no. The only finite set that can satisfy 2 can only contain $0$.

Comment: +1 your comment about $x^n \phi_k(x)$ was useful.

Answer (score -1):

"When $n=\infty$".

It's not just polynomials. Any function that is analytical at 0 has a Taylor expansion
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n},$$
so they are all in.

And then you can expand that with $\{x^{-1}, x^{-2},...\}$ which account for a whole bunch of functions that are not analytical at zero.

So no - it's not just polynomials.

Comment: The question is about a set of basis functions with a given condition and not function representation.

Comment: "is the space of polynomials the only space that meets these conditions?" - that is the question that I answered. No, it is not.